# Why does this sentence use a preposition 'with'?

Tags: prepositions

**With** social networking services (SNS) such as Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram, you can connect with people all around the world.

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: No sure what you're getting at here. Prepositions add meaning to nouns. For eg: about, with, for, besides. Without the **with** in your sentence, there is no connection to **social networking sites** and **you** (you—who can connect with people).

Comment: *With* equals *by means of* in this sentence.

Comment: You could also substitute the word *using*.

Answer (score 2):

"You can connect with people all around the world **with** social networking services."

*Prepositions* connect *clauses* together into *complex sentences*.  A complex sentence is one which has a *principal clause* and one or more *subordinate clauses*.  Subordinate clauses are also known as *dependent clauses*.

The first clause is "You can connect with people all around the world".  This is the principal clause.  It can stand on its own as a sentence, independently of the other clause.

The second clause is "social networking services (SNS) such as Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram"  This is a subordinate clause.  It is only useful as a fragment of a longer sentence. It expands upon the information in the principal clause.

To connect a subordinate clause into a sentence, you need to connect it to the principal clause.  The grammatical tool for bolting a subordinate clause to a principal clause is called a *preposition*.

The more usual placement of a subordinate clause is *after* the principal clause.  In these cases, the preposition sits at the beginning of the subordinate clause, and as a result the preposition naturally sits between the two clauses.

In this example, the statement has the sentence of the form *subordinate clause [followed by] principal clause*.  The preposition still sits at the start of the subordinate clause, *even though* it is still acting as the connection between the two clauses.  This is because it is, in a sense,  telling *how* the subordinate clause relates to the principal clause.

Answer (score 0):

It means, by having/using those services, you can achieve your connection with people around the world. Think of the negative:

> **Without** SNS you would not be able to connect with people (as easily)

You could easily substitute **using** or **through** in the sentence.
Some languages show this relationship explicitly, for example Japanese uses **de** to mean *by way of*.